# err in while crating item in database

Tags: json, mongodb, express, mern

This my code:

```
router.post("/AddFooditem",ownerMiddleware,async(req,res)=>{
    //change the jwt token when you signed new in the application in the postman...
    const foodName=req.body.foodName;
    const foodDescription=req.body.foodDescription;
    const foodImage=req.body.foodImage;
    const price=req.body.price;

    const foodItem=await Fooditems.findOne({foodName});
    if(foodItem==null){
        Fooditems.create({foodName:foodName,foodDescription:foodDescription,foodImage:foodImage,price:price});
        res.status(200).send(`Food item is Created ${foodName}`)
    }
    else{
        res.status.json({msg:`${foodName} is already exists`})
    }
})
```

After clicking this route the response comes like this:

[image: postman output]

But in database:

[image: mongodb database output]

I want output in the database like this:

```
{
    "foodName":"pulihora",
    "foodDescription":"pulihora with Lemon Rice",
    "foodImage":"https://google.com/puilhora",
    "foodprice":100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose `Model.create` method just prepares your query, it doesn't execute it. This means your `res.status(200).send('Food item is Created ${foodName}')` was executed immediately after so the request/response cycle was complete.

In order to execute it so that your new document is saved to the collection you need to either call the `then()` function or use `async/await` pattern. If you chain `exec()` when using `async/await` you will get better debugging capability because `exec()` returns a promise and will have a full stack trace.

In short, you can do either:

```js
if(foodItem==null){
   await Fooditems.create({
      foodName:foodName, 
      foodDescription:foodDescription, 
      foodImage:foodImage, 
      price:price
   });
   res.status(200).send(`Food item is Created ${foodName}`)
} else{
   res.status.json({msg:`${foodName} is already exists`})
}
```

Or

```js
if(foodItem==null){
   Fooditems.create({
      foodName:foodName, 
      foodDescription:foodDescription, 
      foodImage:foodImage, 
      price:price
   }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send(`Food item is Created ${foodName}`)
   })
} else{
   res.status.json({msg:`${foodName} is already exists`})
}
```

As an aside you have no error handling in your route handler callback so you don't know if your database queries are throwing any errors. You should implement `try/catch` blocks or leverage a `catchAsync` function to deal with errors.

An example would be:

```js
router.post("/AddFooditem", ownerMiddleware, async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        //change the jwt token when you signed new in the application in the postman...
        const foodName=req.body.foodName;
        const foodDescription=req.body.foodDescription;
        const foodImage=req.body.foodImage;
        const price=req.body.price;

        const foodItem = await Fooditems.findOne({foodName});
        if(!foodItem){
            await Fooditems.create({
                foodName:foodName,
                foodDescription:foodDescription,
                foodImage:foodImage,
                price:price
            });
            res.status(201).send(`Food item is Created ${foodName}`)
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).json({
                msg:`${foodName} already exists`
            })
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            msg:`Error on server.`
        })
    }
});
```